# Nodejs gRPC error with { [Error] code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }

Tags: node.js, tcp, http2, grpc

I used gRPC In my application, but I got an error like this  { [Error] code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }, I can't understand what's meaning. thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 0):

This means that the server you sent the request to responded with status code 14: Unavailable. This is supposed to be a temporary status, so you should be able to successfully make the request just by sending it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again .