# "internal_metadta error" when using Blockchain as a service on bluemix account

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

We are using Blockchain as a service on a Bluemix account. 
We have been using node-sdk to deploy, invoke, and query transactions on Bluemix. 
Currently, we are facing an error on Bluemix when I call, invoke, or query function for the first time. The error says `internal_metadata error.` But if I call the functions for a second time, it works correctly. After some time (say 10 minutes) if we again call this function, it gives the same error.

Problem is similar to [38893402](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893402/nodejs-grpc-error-with-error-code-14-metadata-metadata-internal-repr)

Answer (score 0):

I work for IBM Blockchain support. For this type of problem I suggest that you open a support ticket via the Bluemix dashboard. We will be happy to assist you with providing a solution. 
Thanks for using IBM and blockcahin.